# How to get my gallery to slider in twig file?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have rendered all my pictures from gallery, but need to get them to slider in my twig file.. is that possible without using any plugin, please???

My code, php:

```
<?php

$context = Timber::get_context();
$context["post"] = Timber::get_post();


Timber::render( 'pages/single/single-one-collection.twig', $context, CACHE_TIME);
```

My twig:

```
 {% for picture in post.get_field('oc_gallery') %}
                <div class="section" id="section{{ loop.index }}">
                    <img src="{{ TimberImage(picture).src | resize(400, 266)}}" alt="" />
                </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: It's fairly unclear what you're asking I feel. Are you using WordPress? If you're wanting gallery-like functionality, you'll certainly need a plugin or roll your own.

Comment: yes, I work with the wordpress and I need to get my gallery on twig website to slider...

Comment: To my knowledge, WordPress doesn't use Twig, so I'm assuming you're shifting your code over to a code base that does. In that case, you'll still need a JS-based gallery library of some sort to make this happen.

Comment: Yes, your are write, I use wordpress but is also mixed with php... JS-based gallery are you saying?

Comment: Yes, that is my recommendation.

Comment: And do you have some example similar to my code example, please?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't the place to seek recommendations for 3rd party libraries or resources. But a simple Google search turns up plenty of viable options. Google "Image libraries for PHP / JS"